# How do I delete all items driving a List view in SwiftUI even if a user is editing an item?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have the following simple setup for a macOS SwiftUI desktopapp. When I try to delete all items by emptying the items array it works fine unless the user has placed the cursor in one of the TextField items.

In those cases I get an application crash and the error "Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range"

How can I implement a "Delete All" method that doesn't trigger the error?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var text: String
    let id: UUID
    
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}


struct ItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $item.text)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items: [Item] = [Item(text: "First"),
                 Item(text: "Second"),
                 Item(text: "Third")]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // If the user has placed the cursor in a text field the app
                    // will crash when deleting all items.
                    // Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range
                    items.removeAll()

                }, label: {
                    Text("Delete all")
                })
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    ItemView(item: $items[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also tried looping without indices but get the same error.

```swift
ForEach($items) { $item in
   ItemView(item: $item)
}
```

Comment: In SwiftUI, it is almost never advisable to use indices in a `ForEach`. You should iterate over the items themselves. Look up "SwiftUI element binding syntax"

Comment: This seems to only happen if you put the ForEach inside the List. If you pull the ForEach outside of the List, it's fine.